# RXJS - How to repeat a subscription after some periods

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient, polling

I want to repeat the same REST call subscription every 15000ms (polling). I tried this:

```
foo() {
    return this.httpClient.get('/rest')
    .pipe(
      delay(15000),
      repeat(),
    );
}

//...
this.foo().subscribe(() => console.log('HEY'));
```

Which works well except for it delays the first emission after 15000ms. So, how can I have the same result without have to wait for the first delay?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `interval` call to create an observable which repeatedly emits after the predefined delay. Then you only have to `mergeMap` that observable to your network call.

```js
foo() {
    return interval(15000).pipe(
      mergeMap(() => this.httpClient.get('/rest')),
    );
}

//...
this.foo().subscribe(() => console.log('HEY'));
```

Comment: Interval will also delay the first call

Comment: Interval delays the first emission, you need to use timer(0,15000), and as a practice, switchMap is the better operator here

Comment: @bryan60 This should be the answer

Comment: @bryan60 whoops, then I got this wrong. You should post that as an answer ... except, why is `switchMap` better? We don't know what the OP wants to do with the results of the calls.

Comment: this will make a new request every 15s, even if the request takes longer than 15s. It won't wait for the request to finish before counting the 15s

Comment: if @AlexBiro integrates his answer I'll accept it. Thanks bryan60

Comment: SwitchMap is preferred on an interval because it maintains at most one active inner subscription and will not block subsequent requests if one gets stuck.

Comment: @bryan60 `mergeMap` will also not block anything, it will dispatch a new request as the events come in, and subscribes to them, regardless of status of the previous requests. Again, the `switchMap` vs. `mergeMap` question depends on what the OP wants and what the requests do.

Comment: @Nemus I don't want to take it, as my original answer was incorrect. If nothing else, post the correct answer yourself, and mention that it's based on the other comments.

Comment: Prior hanging requests should be canceled on an interval. SwitchMap is the right operator

Answer (score 0):

You could store the value to delay by in a local variable, which is initialized to 0, and then updated after the first call.

```
foo() {
    let delayBy = 0;
    return this.httpClient.get('/rest')
    .pipe(
      delay(delayBy),
      tap(() => delayBy = 15000),
      repeat()
    );
}
```

Edit: Bryan's suggestion of timer(0, 15000) is better than this

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried but following should work.

The main difference with other answer is that **it'll wait for the request to finish** before waiting 15s and poll again.

```
const mockRequest = () =>
  of("mockedRequest").pipe(
    // simulate network latency
    delay(500)
  );

const myRequest = () => {
  return mockRequest().pipe(
    switchMap(res =>
      concat(of(res), timer(DELAY_BETWEEN_REQUESTS).pipe(ignoreElements()))
    ),
    repeat()
  );
};
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5fg2ov?file=index.ts